# Reference Transactions without Paypal Account

Tags: paypal, reference, transactions, paypal-subscriptions

For a new project I want to get rid of paypal subscriptions as users tend to subscribe multiple times and then dispute all payments.

Instead I want to use reference transactions to bill the clients when necessary.

Now with the regular checkout or subscriptions users didn't have to have a Paypal account to purchase. They could just enter credit card details and start the subscriptions.

With reference transactions I can only see a paypal login page where a user gives permission for the reference transaction.

Is there a way to enable reference transactions for users without a Paypal account that just have a credit card? Or is there something similar that could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Reference Transactions PayPal Accounts are required and not allowed for Guest Checkout option (no work around).

The alternative to this would be to upgrade using Payflow APIs where a PNREF is used in this scenario on future payments. Or BrainTree's future payments using vault. These options are direct Credit Card processing only.

Recap - PayPal accounts needed for PayPal Reference Transactions

Answer (score 0):

Payments Pro has a reference transaction system. Typically you run an authorization for $1 and then void it. Then you can run a [reference transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#example-reference-transaction) on the previous transaction ID.

Payments Pro is a subscription service.